# Discord JDA getMentionedMembers() sometimes not working

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

[image: The GIF]

I'm using `event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers().get(0)` to get the member but before that I allways make a check to see if the size of the mentioned members list is greater than 0 and if it is it sends the embed if not it sends the `The report command wasn't used correctly. Type =help to find out more.` message. As you can see in the GIF, it only works if I type it manualy and not if I copy it even though discord recognises it as a mention. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: You should include your code in the question rather than describing it. That makes it a lot easier to answer and explain bugs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.